# How to get the list of all hyperparameters for an ML algorithm like Linear Regression in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I'm learning to build Machine Learning models using `Spark` `DataFrames` API in `scala` and want to know the list of all hyper-parameters that can be used for tuning the model. By searching so far, I found a few hyper-parameters for `LinearRegression` like:

- setMaxIter
- setRegParam
- setElasticNetParam

which can be used in the following way:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression

val lr = new LinearRegression().setMaxIter(100).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)
val lrModel = lr.fit(training)
```

Is there a documentation page or a method in Spark which can list of all the tunable hyper-parameters? Something like:

```
LinearRegression.getParamList()
RandomForest.getParamList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [ml-tuning](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html), take advantage of `ML-Pipelines` where you will pass you selection of features through`ParamGridBuilder` to`CrossValidator`, and run pipeline to estimate which sets performs best, below example:

```
val lr = new LinearRegression()
.setMaxIter(10)

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
.addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
.addGrid(lr.fitIntercept)
.addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.0, 0.5, 1.0))
.build()

val trainValidationSplit = new TrainValidationSplit()
.setEstimator(lr)
.setEvaluator(new RegressionEvaluator)
.setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
.setTrainRatio(0.8)

val model = trainValidationSplit.fit(training)
```

further you can explore scala docs [ml.param](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params), there is a method `explainParam()` but I have not used it [api/scala/pipeline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel)

Comment: `val lr = new LinearRegression(); lr.explainParams` did it for me. Also `lr.extractParamMap` gave the list of current values of all the hyper-parameters. Thanks for the help @KarolSudol